# Sockets in C# and SSL

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, ssl, windows-phone

In my project I have communication layer based on sockets. There I use asynchronous methods like ConnectAsync, SendAsync, ReceiveAsync, etc. I'd like to make the connection more secure, so SSL would be necessary here. I found out that SslStream should be used in such a situation. However, then I'd have to change the communication layer and resign from methods that are not present in SslStream. I'd like to avoid it.

Is there any other workaround such that I could 'wrap' my communication with SSL without resigning from currently used methods? Some time ago I was using Netty framework in my other Java project and it was possible there.

The other question concerns the same situation in Windows Phone/Silverlight platforms. Someone proposed to use SecureBlackbox as the solution, but it isn't rather option for me because it requires money.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Comment: `SslStream`, like all streams, has `ReadAsync`/`WriteAsync`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Ok, but still I'd have to change my communication layer and I want to avoid it. Moreover, SslStream doesn't have all counterparts of methods from Socket class.

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything better, short of writing your own wrapper on top of `SslStream` which emulates the sockets interface.

Comment: If you target Silverlight and Windows Phone, it's really the best idea to take SecureBlackbox's classes and rewrite the code to use them. The reason is that sockets are *very* different in desktop, Silverlight and Windows Phone, and you'll waste weeks making them work.

Comment: I spent a lot of time to find a free solution to this. It finished by buying SecureBlackbox.. The SslStream implementation in WP API is very incomplete.